# Using read command to read file by line in Bash doesn't work

Tags: bash, shell, read

I have a `text.txt` file like this

```
line1
line2
line3
```

I want to write a script that loops over each line and echo out

```
modified line1
modified line2
modified line3
```

This is the script which is a very common solution:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo modified $line
done <<< $(cat ~/text.txt)
```

But the output I got was:

`modified line1 line2 line3`

What went wrong?

Comment: the `<<< $(cat ...)` command substitution + here string is completely unnecessary and messing things up, but I guess that you're using some older (< 4.0?) version of `bash`, which will ifs-split+glob the word following `<<<`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this. Now that I think about it, it's definitely unnecessary. But could you explain what you meant by `ifs-split+glob the word following <<<`?

Comment: The shell will split unquoted variables using the characters from the `IFS` variable and then glob-expand the resulting words (eg. `a='* .*'; echo $a`). This should **not** happen on a variable used as a here-string (eg. `a='* .*'; cat <<<$a` should print just `* .*`), but it does happen on some older buggy versions of `bash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the last line, you don't need the variable (command substitution) or `cat`, since `read` already can read the file. If you instead do this:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo modified $line
done < ~/text.txt
```

It works.

Additionally, your command would work if you quoted the variable like:

```
"$(cat ~/text.txt)"
```

since bash disregards newlines in variables unless you quote them. But doing it this way is overcomplicating it.

Comment: what is "the variable of cat"?

Comment: @mosvy I don't know. I never mentioned "the variable of cat". I said he doesn't need the `cat` command or the variable (the result of the `cat` command) in the last line.

Comment: This really works. Thank you. 
I understand that using `command substitution` and `heredoc` is not necessary here, but I don't understand why that combination doesn't work. Would you mind explaining that?

Comment: @TranTriet bash disregards newlines in variables unless you quote them. If you had you used double quotes around the command like `"$(cat /tmp/text.txt)"` it would work, but this is overcomplicating it.

Comment: @DisplayName ah, sorry, of != or

Comment: This answer is correct, but it doesn't address *why* the command substitution is a problem (or a potential problem) here. I'd recommend expanding the answer to explain that. Also, it seems this problem only exists in older versions of baah, so including that information would be very useful as well.